# How to use gist markdown embed Google-CSE?

Tags: markdown, embed, google-custom-search, gist

I want to embed Google-CSE on gist markdown, then embed this on Medium.

Final purpose: Show the search bar on Medium

Tried:

1.Can't embed Google-CSE directly on Medium.

https://i.imgur.com/DPGiV6X.jpg

---

2.Use markdown embed on gist(All failed)

2-1.`<iframe></iframe>`

2-2.`<object></object>`

2-3.`<script></script>`

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '015605450483368086706:7jlic1sqlvi';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

2-4.`<embed src="https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=018064005093677680301:cmhz2glhxjy" width=200 height=200 />`

---

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed anything on any GitHub.com pages including gists.

GitHub documents their entire markup processing process in [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup). Relevant here is step 2:

> 2. The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or
>      `id` attributes.

The sanitizer will remove any of the pieces needed to embed most anything in the page. A [previous version](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/2b0bdcfa322ff2c282b5c7dbdf19d69bf6085b1d/README.md#github-markup) of that document pointed to the actual [sanitation filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb), which disallows `script`, `iframe`, `object` and `embed` tags, among others (technically, the filter disallows everything which is not on the [whitelist](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L38-L47) and all of those tags are not on the whitelist). The filter strips all disallowed tags and/or attributes and their contents from the document. As the [update](https://github.com/github/markup/commit/56a58500418779ee3e06db2bfcd86654acbf2ce7) which removed the link to the filter provides no explanation, we can't be sure GitHub still uses the same filter, but it is reasonable to expect that if they changed filters, the new filter would have very similar behavior.

If you are curious why GitHub would feel the need to disallow such things, then I suggest you learn about the dangers of cross-site scripting (XSS). No doubt there are other possible attacks that this prevents as well, but XSS is certainly serious enough in itself to justify disallowing any third party scripts of any kind.